# ¿Cómo obtener el primer y último carácter de una cadena o entero y sustituir lo demás con asterisco en java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Quiero crear un método con retorno para obtener el primer y último carácter o dígito y al imprimirlo muestre el primer dato(asterisco) último dato.

Ejemplo:

123456789
1*******9

Igual con una cadena de texto

```
public  String  mostrarPrimerUltimoCaracter(@PathParam("texto") String texto){

    String str1="*"; // caracter a sustituir / * /
    char primerElemento=texto.charAt(0);
    char ultimoElemento=texto.charAt(texto.length()-1);




     /*Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Ingresar los digitos");
    numero = sc.nextLine();*/

    for (int i=0; i<texto.length();i++){
        if (texto.length() >= 2){

            texto.replaceAll("[0-8]","*");


        } else{
            System.err.println("\nNo se permite\n");
        }


    }
   


    return texto.substring(0,texto.length()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te sirve algo asi?:

```
public  String  mostrarPrimerUltimoCaracter(String texto){
  char[] chararr = texto.toCharArray(); // pasamos la cadena a un array de caracteres
  for(int i=1; i<texto.length()-1; i++) // recorremos ignorando el primer indice y el ultimo
    chararr[i] = '*'; // reemplazamos por *
  return String.valueOf(chararr); // devolvemos el array no sin antes volverlo a convertir a string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te adjunto mi solución. Puedes inicializar dos **`char[]`** para obtener al primer caracter y último caracter del texto que recibas:

```
char[] first;
char[] last;

first = texto.split("")[0].toCharArray(); // obtengo el primer caracter
last = texto.split("")[texto.length() - 1].toCharArray(); // obtengo el último caracter
```

Luego dibujas los asteriscos, en donde se repetirán en base a la longitud de la cadena - 2 ya que no estamos contando al primer y último caracter:

```
String asteriscos = "";

for (int i = 0; i < texto.length() - 2; i++) {
    asteriscos += "*"; // se aumentarán los asteriscos de la longitud del texto - 2, ya que no contamos al primer y último caracter
}
```

Ahora, el resultado de **`first`** y **`last`** devuelve los caracteres entre corchetes, fácilmente lo quitamos usando una expresión regular:

```
String firstNumber = Arrays.toString(first).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""); // "first" trae [1], entonces quitamos los corchetes con regex
String lastNumber = Arrays.toString(last).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""); // "last" trae [9], entonces quitamos los corchetes con regex
```

Y luego, concatenamos en el último **`return`** los resultados finales:

```
return firstNumber + asteriscos + lastNumber; // concatenamos todos los resultados
```

El código final vendría a ser el siguiente:

```
public static String mostrarPrimerUltimoCaracter(String texto) {
    char[] first;
    char[] last;
    
    String asteriscos = "";
    
    first = texto.split("")[0].toCharArray(); // obtengo el primer caracter
    last = texto.split("")[texto.length() - 1].toCharArray(); // obtengo el último caracter
    
    for (int i = 0; i < texto.length() - 2; i++) {
        asteriscos += "*"; // se aumentarán los asteriscos de la longitud del texto - 2, ya que no contamos al primer y último caracter
    }
    
    String firstNumber = Arrays.toString(first).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""); // "first" trae [1], entonces quitamos los corchetes con regex
    String lastNumber = Arrays.toString(last).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""); // "last" trae [9], entonces quitamos los corchetes con regex

    return firstNumber + asteriscos + lastNumber; // concatenamos todos los resultados
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(mostrarPrimerUltimoCaracter("123456789"));
    System.out.println(mostrarPrimerUltimoCaracter("999999999999"));
    System.out.println(mostrarPrimerUltimoCaracter("123456"));
}
```

**Output:**

```
// 1*******9
// 9**********9
// 1****6
```